# syntax error in C prog

Tags: c

I am trying to compile my code with a "C" compiler in my IDE. But don't know what the problem is with these few lines.

[image: Code #1]

the error  : `syntax error near '='`

[image: Code #2]

the errors : `'_print': different length of parameter lists` and `'_print':too many actual parameters`

BUT the same code runs perfectly with "C++" compiler. I just get error on "C" compiler.

Can anyone give me any idea about it ?

Comment: Because C and C++ are different languages. C does not have support for default values for function arguments. And please do not post code as images. Paste code as formatted text into your question.

Answer (score 0):

C does not have function overload, nor default arguments as C++ does, so if you need to handle `int` and `long` differently, you will need one function per type, like this:

```
void print_int(int n, int base);
void print_long(long n, int base);
```

But in your code, since you are just calling the `long` version in the `int` function, you can just have one function:

```
void print(long n, int base);
```

and if it is called on `int`, the argument is automatically promoted to `long`.

```
int n = 123;
print(n, 10);
```